# Problem with group by first letter JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a problem with my code. I need to group the contacts like that:

```
A.

ADRIAN
ANDREI
ANGEL



B.

BENY
BORRIS

Z.

ZEYN

etc.
```

I have a code for that, but it's displaying wrong.So, I need to group every contact by first letter.

Here is my code :

```
    <section>
      <label class="select">
             <ul style="list-style: none;right: 40px; position: relative" id="destPopuler">
           @foreach($users->contact as $user)

                     @if( $user->role[0]->pivot->role_id == 1 )
           <li class="country">
                     <div class="products">
                     <h3 style="margin-bottom: 30px"><a href="{{ url('') }}/{{$user->username }}"><input class="my_div" id="{{$user->username}}" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" <?php if(isset($replyMessage)){ if($replyMessage == $user->id) { echo "checked"; } } ?>><span class="name" style="padding: 5px" >{{ $user->username }}</a></h3>
                 </div>
                 </span></li>
                     @endif

                 @endforeach
</ul>
       </label>
    </section>


$('.products > h3').each(function () {
  var letter = $('a', this).text().charAt(0);

  if (!$(this).parent().find('[data-letter="'+ letter +'"]').length) {
    $(this).parent().append('<div data-letter="'+ letter+'"><span>'+ letter +'</span></div>');
  }
  $(this).parent().find('[data-letter="'+ letter +'"]').append(this);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Why you need `javascript` for grouping?. You can easily do it in `laravel` itself using `collection` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby.

Comment: Hey, James. I tried to use a lot of methods but only this is working for the moment.The problem is that I use Laravel 5.2, and I don't know if this is working for me.

Comment: please check my answer. It should give you an idea to implement it in laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to group your users in `javascript` while you have enough control of data in `laravel` itself. You can group the users using [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-groupby) of laravel [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections).

I'll try to give you an example.

In your controller while retrieving the `users` group it with `username` field.

```
$results = $collection->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {  // Replace the $collection with whatever variable you have
    return substr($item['username'], 0, 1);
});
```

And in view, you need to have 2 for loops.

```
@foreach($results as $char => $users)
   <div data-letter="{{$char}}"><span>{{$char}}</span></div>
   @foreach($users->contact as $user)
       @if( $user->role[0]->pivot->role_id == 1 )
           <li class="country">
              <div class="products">
                 <h3 style="margin-bottom: 30px"><a href="{{ url('') }}/{{$user->username }}"><input class="my_div" id="{{$user->username}}" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" <?php if(isset($replyMessage)){ if($replyMessage == $user->id) { echo "checked"; } } ?>><span class="name" style="padding: 5px" >{{ $user->username }}</a></h3>
               </div>
             </li>
         @endif    
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Note that this is just an example. However, it should work fine once you format it to your datastructure. `Laravel 5.2` does have `groupBy` support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a question. Here, where you wrote this `Replace the $collection with whatever variable you have `,  should I replace it with `$users` ? Or what variable? Here is my controller right now : https://jsfiddle.net/h1gtpfsa/

Comment: Yes, It should be `$user`, if it is the parent collection.

Comment: Ok, so with `$user` my page is loading, but now in my view I don't have any contact here :(

Comment: Can you share the dump(`dd` or `var_dump`) of the `$results`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200802/discussion-between-andrew-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding "group" `DIV` to the parent of current `H3` element, which is always `DIV` with class `products`. It also looks like every `LI` item you're creating has its own `DIV.products`. So, you end up with group `DIV` added for each of the `LI` items separately.

Try to create group `DIV` somewhere else, i.e., create separate list with groups of items and hide original list. Or add "fake" `LI` elements with group name (a letter "M" in your example) between other list elements and just move items around between those "fake" elements.

Comment: Hey. Can you show me an example based on my code please? I want a better explaining based on this.